# I activate venv in vscode but it doesnt appear in terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

[image]

I have no idea whats going on but I activated venv by using `Scripts/activate` and it doesnt working yet, the `(venv)` isnt appearing

please someone could help me? I tried everything I could find lol

Comment: Which terminal are you using? Are you using powershell or cmd? If powershell, be sure to run `Scripts/activate.ps1`. In cmd use `Scripts/activate.bat`.

Comment: what is the purpose of this big white part of the image

Comment: look in the script you call (it is text) if it is suited for the terminal/shell you are using, look at all variants of `activate` in that directory

Comment: What system are you using? what terminal? How did you create the environment? Why simply say your mistakes? You should provide detailed information so others can solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Git Bash or a similar bash-like system for Windows. You need to run `Scripts/activate.sh` in this environment.

For PowerShell, use `Scripts/activate.ps1`, and for cmd use `Scripts/activate.bat`.

Answer (score 0):

What terminal are you using? Please create a new *powershell* or *cmd* terminal. Also you should not open the folder of the virtual environment as a workspace. Below are the correct steps.

1. Create a new folder as a workspace, then open this folder in vscode
2. Create a new terminal using the following command to create a virtual environment

   ```
   python -m venv .venv
   ```
3. Use the following command to activate the environment after creation

   ```
   .venv\scripts\activate
   ```
4. Another way is to select the interpreter of the virtual environment in the ***Select Interpreter*** panel after creating the environment

   [image]
5. And then the new terminal will automatically activate the environment

   [image]

*You can read [creating-environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_creating-environments) and [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).*